# How can I see what the name is of a TextBox in class module?

Tags: excel, vba, textbox

I am not to experienced with VBA and I would like to know the name of the TextBox in the class module. I have tried and searched but cannot find the solution.

```
Public WithEvents cl_tekstvak As MSForms.TextBox

Sub cl_tekstvak_change()
    cl_tekstvak.BackColor = IIf(cl_tekstvak = "", &H8000000F, &HC0FFFF)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple actually.

```
Sub cl_tekstvak_change()
    MsgBox cl_tekstvak.Name
    
    cl_tekstvak.BackColor = IIf(cl_tekstvak = "", &H8000000F, &HC0FFFF)
End Sub
```

So if you want to have different actions for different textbox then you can try somthing like this

```
Sub cl_tekstvak_change()
    Select Case cl_tekstvak.Name
        Case "TextBox1"
            cl_tekstvak.BackColor = IIf(cl_tekstvak = "", &H8000000F, &HC0FFFF)
        Case "TextBox2"
            '~~> Do Something else
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. You have been a great help for me.

Comment: Yes, it absolutely did. Your extra comment for different actions is also very usefull.

Comment: It is correct what yoo write, but I must have done something what caused that I cannot get it working again. You are completely right and I don't consider myself very smart.

Comment: @Chielmos What is not working? Can you share the code that you are using? Include as much details as possible :)

Comment: Yes I will do that, but must I make a new question then ?